# Semiring matrix-vector product in Julia not working

Tags: julia

I'm trying to implement the max-plus semiring algebra in Julia (0.6.2), following this paper:

http://www.mit.edu/~kepner/pubs/JuliaSemiring_HPEC2013_Paper.pdf

The type definition for max-plus numbers and the definitions of all relevant operators, taken straight from the paper mentioned above, are as follows:

```
# define max-plus number type

immutable MPNumber{T} <: Number 
  val::T
end

+(a::MPNumber, b::MPNumber) = MPNumber(max(a.val, b.val))

*(a::MPNumber, b::MPNumber) = MPNumber(a.val + b.val)

show(io::IO, k::MPNumber) = show(io, k.val)

zero{T}(::MPNumber{T}) = MPNumber(typemin(T))

one{T}(::MPNumber{T}) = MPNumber(zero(T))

promote_rule{T<:Number}(::Type{MPNumber}, ::Type{T}) = MPNumber

mparray(A::Array) = map(MPNumber, A)

array{T}(A::Array{MPNumber{T}}) = map(x->x.val, A)
```

Basic tests of max-plus addition and multiplication work just fine, e.g.

```
MPNumber(1) + MPNumber(1)
```

gives `MPNumber(1)`, as expected. Max-plus matrix exponentiation, as shown in the paper, also works like a charm:

```
A = mparray(Array([[1, 2] [3, 4]]))
A*A
```

gives

```
2×2 Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}:
 MPNumber{Int64}(5)  MPNumber{Int64}(7)
 MPNumber{Int64}(6)  MPNumber{Int64}(8)
```

However, when I try to multiply a max-plus vector with a max-plus matrix,

```
A = mparray(Array([[1, 2] [3, 4]]))
x = mparray([1, 2])

A*x
```

I get the following error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type MPNumber{Int64}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor MPNumber{Int64}(...) since type constructors fall back to convert methods.

Stacktrace:
 [1] generic_matvecmul!(::Array{MPNumber{Int64},1}, ::Char, ::Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}, ::Array{MPNumber{Int64},1}) at ./linalg/matmul.jl:434
 [2] Ac_mul_B(::Array{MPNumber{Int64},1}, ::Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}) at ./linalg/rowvector.jl:227
```

I'm still fairly new to Julia, so I'm having a hard time working out exactly what it is that's going wrong here and how it can be fixed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is tested under Julia 0.6.2.
Use the following code:

```
struct MPNumber{T} <: Number
  val::T
end
Base.:+(a::MPNumber, b::MPNumber) = MPNumber(max(a.val, b.val))
Base.:*(a::MPNumber, b::MPNumber) = MPNumber(a.val + b.val)
Base.show(io::IO, k::MPNumber) = show(io, k.val)
Base.zero(::MPNumber{T}) where T = MPNumber(typemin(T))
Base.one(::MPNumber{T}) where T = MPNumber(zero(T))
Base.zero(::Type{MPNumber{T}}) where T = MPNumber(typemin(T))
Base.one(::Type{MPNumber{T}}) where T = MPNumber(zero(T))
mparray(A::Array) = map(MPNumber, A)
```

(I recommend you to start with this part only as conversions and promotions are more tricky and not needed for your purposes).

Observe that the crucial part is that I am extending functions from `Base` by prepending `Base.` before them. For `+` and `*` you need to additionally use `:` before function names.

Now you can run all you wanted:

```
julia> MPNumber(1) + MPNumber(1)
1

julia> A = mparray(Array([[1, 2] [3, 4]]))
2×2 Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> A*A
2×2 Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}:
 5  7
 6  8

julia> A = mparray(Array([[1, 2] [3, 4]]))
2×2 Array{MPNumber{Int64},2}:
 1  3
 2  4

julia> x = mparray([1, 2])
2-element Array{MPNumber{Int64},1}:
 1
 2

julia> A*x
2-element Array{MPNumber{Int64},1}:
 5
 6
```

as wanted.

EDIT: I have made `zero` and `one` definitions in your code to be more complete and follow standard requirements.

Comment: Just tried it on my machine, everything works fine. Thanks a lot! Would you happen to know where I can learn more about why I need two definitions of zero and one here in order to make it work? I find all this really quite interesting.

Comment: It is a convention only. In Julia you want both `zero(MPNumber{Int64})` and `zero(MPNumber(1))` to produce zero of your type. You can read about both modes e.g. here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Literal-zero-and-one-1. Actually you do not need to define `one` and `zero` at all if you define `Base.convert(::MPNumber{T}, x) where T = MPNumber(T(x))` and all else will just work. But I see that in the paper they were defined.